# Would this 5.5V transient voltage suppressor be damaged at 15V?

Tags: datasheet, tvs, maximum-ratings

I have a circuit which is designed to be powered with a 5VDC source, but has been powered accidentally by a 15VDC source for a couple of seconds.

On the PCB I see a transient voltage suppressor (TVS), whose datasheet can be found [here](https://www.mouser.be/Search/DownloadDatasheet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mouser.be%2Fdatasheet%2F2%2F240%2FLittelfuse_TVS_Diode_Array_SP05_Datasheet.pdf-777043.pdf) (the exact one I have is SP0504BAHTG - SOT23-5.)

I suspect this component has been exposed to the 15VDC. Unfortunately, the datasheet doesn't mention anything about absolute maximum ratings for Vin (it *does* mention that it works up to 5VDC in, but that doesn't imply by itself that the thing would be damaged above 5VDC.)

Would you consider it likely that this thing is broken/damaged?

Comment: If you genuinely applied 15 volts, it would have died in a few milliseconds.

Comment: Some TVS have a rather gradual limiting voltage curve. It may survive a second of 3x over-voltage, especially if the 15v was current-limited.  But the voltage across it may have risen to ~12v or so.  Hopefully something else didn't get damaged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Would you consider it likely that this thing is broken/damaged?*

Yes I would but, there are certain things you can decipher from the data sheet that might help you see why (such as this): -

[image]

So, with an ESD discharge voltage of +8 kV, the TVS diode would limit the peak voltage to about 12 volts. To get deeper you have to look at what MIL-STD-883 is all about. MIL-STD-883 is the human body model and uses this test circuit: -

[image]

So, 8 kV is the charged capacitor voltage and, due to the current limiting resistor (1500 Ω), only 12 volts is produced across the device when subject to the ESD surge. This means that there is an initial peak current of: -

$$\dfrac{8000-12}{1500} \text{ amps} = \text{5.32 amps}$$

So, if you applied a continuous 15 volts, there has to be more current flowing into the tiny device than 5.32 amps so, ask yourself, how long will a little tiny device last when having 15 volts across its terminals and a current of (maybe) 10 amps flowing. That's a power of 150 watts (or maybe it's 100 watts with a little bit of hand waving).

Or maybe your 15 volt supply was current limited to 2 amps but, again, how long would a little itsy-bitsy device in an SOT23-6 package last with maybe 15 or 20 watts applied?

My guess - a few milliseconds - how long was the 15 volt supply connected? If longer than a few milliseconds then this device has gone to meet its maker; it's an ex-TVS diode, it's passed-on; it's a stiff; it is bereft of (useful) life; it's shuffled off its mortal coil and joined the choir invisible.

Comment: +1 for germane Python reference.

Comment: Ah a fellow fan maybe @Reinderien

Answer (score 5):

I have done overvoltage testing on USB powered devices that contain TVS didoes. In my experience, they usually fail short when you do something like this. If it is not pulling down the 5V rail and it is not getting hot during normal (5V) operation, it probably hasn't failed yet. Then again, it may be damaged and ready to fail. If replacing it is an option I would seriously consider replacing it. Otherwise continue using the device but if it stops working, suspect the TVS.

Note: 100 percent for sure if you apply 15V to the diode for several seconds it will fail. But if the power supply is unable to supply several amps (which is likely) then it may have a shot at surviving.

For some reason our QA department wanted our product to survive when 30V was applied to the USB VBUS port. It was a pain in the ass requirement.

Answer (score 3):

[This link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/401169/tvs-diode-clamping-voltage) and then the first answer describes what could possibly be the case. If it would break with 15V it quite possibly would be visibly broken. If the TVS diode looks good, then there is a chance it did it job and the circuit should be fine.